# Java: execution of a statement in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Does a thread run one statement completely at a time or may the statement get split?

For example, in statement below:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println(aString + ": " + ++index);
}
```

What are the the possible execution orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no guarantees when a `Thread` would get pre-empted and hence you cannot assume that a statement would complete *atomically*. In fact, not even your pre-increment `++index` operation is guaranteed to complete without interruption (the reason we have `AtomicInteger`).

It would probably be of no use to enumerate the possible execution orders because they would keep changing from one run of the program to other (assuming there are other threads at play too). That's why we have [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)s and [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) to bring some semblance of control over multi-threaded code.

See [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts may occur at *almost* any time at the instruction level. For instance the String concatenation will consist of constructions of new Strings which will take multiple instructions, any of these potentially being interrupted. The print will also be another instruction potentially interrupted.

If you would like to have a thread execute a segment of code before other threads complete an operation look into:

The **synchronized** keyword
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Or **Locks** and **Semaphores**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that your code/statement will not get interrupted by another thread. But you can use synchronized blocks -

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized( this ) {
       System.out.println(aString+ ": " + ++index);
    }
}
```

This would make sure that no thread tries to interrupt another thread while it is printing.

Comment: Your last statement isn't correct. The synchronized keyword would not stop other threads from interrupting the currently executing thread but would instead block all other threads attempting to execute synchronized methods on that same object or method. You can check it out here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html